# How to add Media control buttons menu selected by moving head in 360 Video player using google cardboard

Tags: android, google-cardboard, google-vr, 360-panorama

How to add Media control buttons menu selected by moving head in 360 Video player using google cardboard only one button.

For example,when I pause video,then the menu shows up.
And I move my head around to select the button in the center of my view and change its color to show it has been selected.

Then I click the cardboard button and control the video 's sound,progress,zoom in and zoom out,lock the view angle and so on.

Hope someone can help me with this function,I am a school student and you can contact me through e-mail 1309476338@qq.com.
I will be appreciated of your help.

Comment: Why no one writing answer from google Team?